# is it safe to define a Helper Class for TCustomWinSocket?

Tags: delphi, winsock

in order to make it more comfortable for me to read/write code, i stacked all those functions into a helper class, so i could avoid all these silly functions in client/server main units, i have put it in a unit that is imported by the two main units, so i'm asking just to make sure i'm not doing anything wrong here.

**so for example**, when i'm inside a ServerSocket event, i can just use it like this:

*Socket.SendString();*

```
  { Extend TCustomWinSocket to make it more comfterable to read and tidy code }
  TCustomWinSocketHelpher = class Helper for TCustomWinSocket
  private
    procedure SendStringLenth(StrLen: Integer);
  public
    function ReceiveStringLength: Integer;
    function ReceiveString(const StrLen: Integer): String;
    function ReceiveStream(StreamLen: Integer; Callback: TUpdateProgBarProc): TMemoryStream;

    procedure SendString(const Str: string);
    procedure SendStreamEx(ASendStream: TStream);
  end;

(*************************** TCustomWinSocketHelpher BEGIN ***************************)

function TCustomWinSocketHelpher.ReceiveString(const StrLen: Integer): String;
var
  S: UTF8String;
begin
  SetLength(S, StrLen);
  ReceiveBuf(PAnsiChar(S)^, StrLen);
  Result := UTF8ToString(S);
end;

function TCustomWinSocketHelpher.ReceiveStringLength: Integer;
begin
  ReceiveBuf(Result, SizeOf(Result));
  Result := ntohl(Result);
end;

function TCustomWinSocketHelpher.ReceiveStream(StreamLen: Integer; Callback: TUpdateProgBarProc): TMemoryStream;
const
  ChunkSize = 4096;
var
  PData: PByte;
  ReadAmount: Integer;
begin
  Result := TMemoryStream.Create;
  GetMem(PData, ChunkSize);
  try
    while StreamLen > 0 do
    begin
      ReadAmount := ReceiveBuf(PData^, Min(ChunkSize, StreamLen));
      if (ReadAmount > 0) then
      begin
        Result.WriteBuffer(PData^, ReadAmount);
        Callback(ReadAmount); // update gui
        Dec(StreamLen, ReadAmount); // update loop condition
      end else
      begin
        OutputDebugString(PChar('ReadAmount ' + Inttostr(ReadAmount)));
      end;
    end;
  finally
    FreeMem(PData);
  end;
end;

procedure TCustomWinSocketHelpher.SendStringLenth(StrLen: Integer);
begin
  StrLen := htonl(StrLen);
  SendBuf(StrLen, SizeOf(StrLen));
end;

procedure TCustomWinSocketHelpher.SendString(const Str: string);
var
  S: UTF8String;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  S := UTF8Encode(Str);
  Len := Length(S);
  SendStringLenth(Len);
  SendBuf(PAnsiChar(S)^, Len);
end;

procedure TCustomWinSocketHelpher.SendStreamEx(ASendStream: TStream);
begin
  ASendStream.Position := 0;
  SendStream(ASendStream);
end;

(*************************** TCustomWinSocketHelpher END ***************************)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly safe to define a helper class.

Comment: You don't *need* to do anything in the helper class. You can do anything you want. A helper class is simply a way to inject new stuff into the scope of another class. You could just as easily write an ordinary standalone function that receives a `TCustomWinSocket` parameter, and then call methods on that object instead of calling them on the implicit `Self` value that a helper class has.

Comment: Hey Rob, i read this "explict/implicit" a lot in the programming scene, how ever i don't fully understand this terms (in the programming scene), can you eplxain to me ?

Comment: *Implicit* means something that's present but isn't seen or mentioned. For example, values of type `PChar` are *implicitly* converted to `string`; you don't have to *explicitly* call `StrPas` to make it happen. Likewise, the object that you call a method on is *implicitly* passed to the method and is available through an *implicitly* declared variable named `Self`. The `Result` variable of a function is also implicitly declared.